# Can I add permissions in Bash for a specific group/user without modifying existing owner/group?

Tags: bash, file, ubuntu, permissions

This may be an odd question but: Is there any way of adding read, write and execute permissions for specific users and/or groups, for a few files, without changing the listed owner/group permissions?

I'm running on Ubuntu 10.10, using bash to install a group of programs. These include Apache2, PHP5. The agent doing the initial installation is root. The agent which ships the code onto the machine is non-root (let's call it "cap"). Root has access of course to /var, /etc and so on. Cap does not. However, Cap is the one which needs to startup and shutdown Apache, place the web application in /var/www, and so on.

Ops are wary of changing group permissions using chmod or chown. E.g. they do not want to see the example below:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 3784 2013-03-29 15:45 file
```

Changing to:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 cap non-root 3784 2013-03-29 15:45 file
```

The only alternative I can see is ACL which seems to have finer grained control of who is allowed to rwx which files. But it seems to need you to remount the partition, which ops will disapprove of.

Can this be achieved?

Comment: What about giving access with `sudoers`?

Comment: why don't you run the installation as root or as sudo ? If you don't belong to the sudo group or don't have the root passwd for the machine, then use a local installation directory.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I'll have to try that out with sudoers but ops apparently does not want the cap user to be part of that list at all. I _can_ run the installation as root and I have also tried using a local installation but that has involved compiling my own binaries which hasn't worked out well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think ACL is your only option. What type of mount is the volume on? I am pretty sure it is enabled by default if it is not NFS. What is the output of getfacl /path/to/file?

Also, if/when you do set an ACL, you may also want to create a soft link to the file/folder if it is contained within a hierarchy that the user or group will not have read/execute permissions on for normal directory traversal.

Comment: I agree, ACLs are the way to go. Remounting can be done on the fly via `mount -o remount ...`, even for the root volume.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with mounts but `mount -l`  gives me: `/dev/mapper/ubuntu-root on / type ext4 (rw,errors=remount-ro)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)rpc_pipefs on /var/lib/nfs/rpc_pipefs type rpc_pipefs (rw)
/dev/sda1 on /boot type ext2 (rw)` besides those listed as `none`. 

And setfacl gives me:
`setfacl -m g:deploy:rwx /var/www/
setfacl: /var/www/: Operation not supported`

Comment: The soft link makes sense, I'll have to try that out. But I hope someone can help me understand why this question is off-topic. I've read the FAQ but maybe I don't understand what constitutes an on-topic programming or software development question.

Comment: This should be in serverfault most likely.